# Differentiability of support function (even for non-convex)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I am reading an economics book (for those who are interested, MWG Microeconomic Theory) and there's a theorem that was just given without proof, but I am interested in the proof - also because I cannot seem to get a good feel for the theorem and maybe the proof would help.

**Theorem:** Let $K$ be a non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (not necessarily convex). Define the support function $\mu_K(\cdot):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ to be $\mu_K(v)=\inf\{v\cdot x : x\in K\}$. Then there is a unique $\tilde{x} \in K$ such that $\tilde{v}\cdot \tilde{x}=\mu_K(\tilde{v})$ if and only if $\mu_K(\cdot)$ is differentiable at $\tilde{v}$. Moreover, in this case, $\nabla \mu_K(\tilde{v})=\tilde{x}$.

**Further query:** In order to get a better feel for the theorem, I thought about the example where $K$ is something like banana-shaped (can't help it, Minions) and $\tilde{v}$ is the direction where there would be two minimizing $\tilde{x}$. However, it is not intuitive to me why $\mu_K(\cdot)$ would not be differentiable at $\tilde{v}$. So as a bonus, does anyone have a good feel on why this is so? Another example I am interested in thinking is convex polygon and $\tilde{v}$ is perpendicular to one of the edges. These will help me get a better feel of the theorem in general.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $K$ is convex or not: the support function of $K$ is equal to the support function of the convex hull of $K$ (and, in fact, the closed convex hull of $K$).

Comment: Also, not that it will change the theorem, but it's worth noting that the support function is typically defined by $\sigma_K(v) = \sup \lbrace v \cdot x : x \in K \rbrace$. What you've defined is $\mu_K(v) = -\sigma_K(-v)$, which makes $\mu_K$ a concave function, not a convex function like $\sigma_K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about the support function geometrically. A hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the equation, in terms of $x$, $v \cdot x = \alpha$ for some $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. The vector $v$ is orthogonal to the hyperplane, and $\alpha$ is proportional to the signed distance to the origin. So, in a sense, when computing the support function of $K$ at a vector $v$, we squeeze $K$ as tightly as we can between two hyperplanes orthogonal to $v$, and the support function measures the (in this case) lesser of the signed distances. But, the important thing to picture here is a set, encased by two parallel hyperplanes.

Now, if you do accept that the support function is differentiable where a unique minimising vector $x \in K$ exists, and the gradient is this vector, then I think I can provide some hand-wavy geometric intuition as to why the support function is not differentiable.

Suppose for a vector $v$ and set $K$, there are two distinct vectors $x_1, x_2 \in K$ such that $v \cdot x_1 = v \cdot x_2 = \mu_K(v)$. What this says is that the minimising hyperplane contains both $x_1$ and $x_2$. In fact, we can assume $x_1$ and $x_2$ are extreme points of the convex hull of $K$.

Now consider what happens when we slightly vary $v$ in various directions. This involves slightly tilting the hyperplanes in various directions, since $v$ determines the normal directions. The enveloping hyperplanes will have to accommodate which, depending on the shape of $K$, might involve widening or narrowing; they need to envelop all of $K$.

If we tilt these hyperplanes so that it favours $x_1$, then the support function is behaving in this direction as though $x_1$ was the one and only minimising point, and hence the support function would behave locally in these directions as though $x_1$ was the gradient. But similarly, if we vary $v$ so that it favours $x_2$, in those directions, the support function would behave locally in those directions as though $x_2$ were the gradient.

So, in different directions, the support function behaves like two different differentiable functions with different gradients, so we have a cusp at $v$.

I know that's terribly vague, but that's my geometric intuition as to why this happens.